# foreman: command not found

Tags: ruby

I am following [this tutorial of Heroku](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-js). I installed foreman with

```
sudo gem install foreman
```

but when I try to use this in the terminal with command

```
foreman
```

this returns

> foreman: command not found

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would check where `gem` installs executables into and add that directory to your PATH.

Answer (score 7):

Just got the same error: *foreman command not found*.
I managed to **succeed removing my gem** with:

```
sudo gem uninstall foreman
```

And **re-install it back with [rvm](http://beginrescueend.com/)**.

```
rvm gem install foreman
```

Good luck!

Comment: This gave me the clue for getting it to work with rbenv: `gem install foreman; rbenv rehash`

Comment: Please note that `rvm gem ...` was removed, try `gem install foreman` or `rvm all do gem install foreman` instead.

Answer (score 4):

```
gem install foreman
```

was all I needed to do

However, when I followed the deb instructions on this page: http://theforeman.org/projects/foreman/wiki/Installation_instructions
I had lots of issues...Eventually, I completely uninstalled before running gem install foreman. Then it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given quite enough information for the problem to be properly diagnosed.  (Eg, give a link to the tutorial, indicate if you tested foreman by itself, and tell us what "this" is, ie what command you entered or selected.)

If the install appeared to be ok, and if `which foreman` reports a reasonable path to `foreman`, and if the invocation that failed is in a non-interactive shell, then the usual problem is a different $PATH value in that shell, and the usual solution is to specify a fully-qualified path.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the accepted answer that the issue might be with `PATH`.

If you run `rbenv` put this to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH="$PATH:~/.rbenv/shims”
```

Then source the file and check for **foreman**: `which foreman`.